# i want to copy from big arr to two small ones

Tags: java, arrays

I want to input my own vallues to big array of 20 and copy that to 2 small ones of 10, then value of second array must be outprinted. Im getting error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException what is wrong with my code. =|

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] test = new int[20];
        int[] testA = new int[10];
        int[] testB = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            test[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            testA[i]= test[i];
        }
        for (int i = 10; i < test.length; i++ ){
            testB[i] = test[i];
            System.out.println(testB[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step of the second loop, you will assign value to `testB[10]`, which causes the error because `testB` only have size of `10` (i.e. `[0~9]`).

You need to change

```
testB[i] = test[i];
System.out.println(testB[i]);
```

to

```
testB[i-10] = test[i];
System.out.println(testB[i-10]);
```

Or you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    testB[i] = test[i+10];
    System.out.println(testB[i]);
}
```

Comment: it worked. Huh? but he start to count from 10 and goes up to 20, and while he doing that he copys values from another array, i dont get, why is there [i - 10]?

Comment: @Predict_it By doing `testB[i] = test[i];`, you assume `testB` and `test` are in the same pace, which is wrong.

Comment: so its like backward loop from the vallue of test or you cut off the start position of test to start with

Comment: @Predict_it No. I added another option. Hope it will help you better understand.

Comment: so you start from 10 and add +1 every cycle

Comment: @Predict_it Start from 10 of `test` because you want to copy its second half values to `testB`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternativley:

```
System.arraycopy( test , 0, testA , 0, 10 );
System.arraycopy( test , 10, testB , 0, 10 );
```